# Unit-test for application with Google Test framework in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest

I'm trying to organize unit-testing of classes in my application.

First of all, it's an application, so it has its own main function. As far as I understand I need to create a separate application which will contain and run tests because GoogleTest needs a special main function to run tests. I created it but if I call anything from my objective project the test project doesn't link.

Is the only way to make it work - is to create three projects - test project, Lib project which has all the classes and run project, which just runs calls on function from Lib project?

Comment: Yes that would be the right way to make it work. Your exe should be a pretty thin layer that inturn relies on the functionality with your dll, which contains all the code.  This way you can use this across a variety of clients eg. commandline, ui, webpage etc